# Updating collection entity issue in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have entity Car and User

```
    @Entity
    public class Car{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;
    String name;
    ........

    @Entity
    public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Car> carList;
    .......
```

I am successfully able to save entity User, but when trying to update User with new Car(ie to add a new Car) like

```
   user.addCars(car);

   updateUser(user);
```

Its giving exception

```
     Hibernate Exception Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

Comment: show complete stacktrace of exception and also show the code when you are getting this error

Comment: Show your DB script also. Car and User tables.